# how do I make URL in qnamaker as plain text instead of hyperlink

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

Background:

I have a requirement to render URL as plain text from QnA Maker where we keep the possible utterances and answer in qnamaker and these answers has few URLs. I am looking for a way to have these answers in such a way that when I want some URL to be hyperlink and some URL being plain text. Plain text URL is need for accessibility purpose.Currently all the URLs are hyperlinked when it is rendered in botframework-webchat. I attempted on [Commonmark](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/07-links.html) to make answer with URL as plain text but I am just wondering if it is possible at all possibly using escape markdown. Please suggest.

Comment: This works I believe, I'll try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706012/how-do-i-prevent-auto-generated-links-in-the-github-wiki

Comment: You even could [refer to this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I did refer that but none of them were able to make it plain text.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/reference-markdown-format.md